# Word counts in Python using regular expression

Tags: python, regex, count, cpu-word

What is the correct way to count English words in a document using regular expression?

I tried with:

```
words=re.findall('\w+', open('text.txt').read().lower())
len(words)
```

but it seems I am missing few words (compares to the word count in gedit).
Am I doing it right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I suggest you try to find out which are words did you miss. The you should be able to improve your regex to include words of that kind.

Comment: shouldn't it be `\\w+` or is this intended?

Comment: @Constantinius: It probably should be `'\\w+'` or `r'\w+'` to be clear, but `\w` isn't a known escape sequence in a Python string, so `'\w+'` gets interpreted as a literal backslash-w-plus.

Comment: Just re-read this question. "English words", you say? Are you verifying against a known dictionary of "English words"? Will you throw out those borrowed from French and other languages?

Comment: Thanks for the comments guys!
@Johnsyweb that was just because my native Language is Chinese, I should have just written "words" instead:)

Answer (score 6):

Using \w+ won't correctly count words containing apostrophes or hyphens, eg "can't" will be counted as 2 words. It will also count numbers (strings of digits); "12,345" and "6.7" will each count as 2 words ("12" and "345", "6" and "7").

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought about that:) it says very clear in the python docs...

Comment: But wait, that only makes my number less not more...:(

Answer (score 1):

This seems to work as expected.

```
>>> import re
>>> words=re.findall('\w+', open('/usr/share/dict/words').read().lower())
>>> len(words)
234936
>>> 
bash-3.2$ wc /usr/share/dict/words
  234936  234936 2486813 /usr/share/dict/words
```

Why are you lowercasing your words? What does that have to do with the count?

I'd submit that the following would be more efficient:

```
words=re.findall(r'\w+', open('/usr/share/dict/words').read())
```

Comment: Yeah, that is completely unnecessary. I just got this piece of code from a program that finds the most used words in a doc, and they used it so that "Hello" and "hello" will be considered as same word.

Comment: @Zhe: lowercasing won't make a difference to this code. If you want to count the number of **unique** words, then it would make a difference. I suggest using a `set` for this.

Answer (score 0):

Once you have list of words by `_words_list = words.split()` or required processing through regex or other methods, you can easily get a count of words with the following method:

```py
import numpy as NP
import pandas as PD

_counted_words = PD.Series(NP.array(_words_list)).value_counts()
```