# How to count daily word frequency from twitter?

Tags: python, regex, twitter, pandas, word-count

I've got a twitter dataframe like this,

```
>>>twitdata=pd.read_csv('D:\\twit-data.csv')
>>>twitdata

    tweet_id    user_id     user_name   t_date      t_time      tweets
    4.05323E+17 82142636    1nvestor    11/26/2013  8:12:00     Fidelity reports that $TSN stock gets called away. Position now closed.
    2.53585E+17 22042454    Kiplinger   10/3/2012   15:57:00    Did you know that every $100 bump in avg. home prices lifts consumer spending by $5? http://t.co/zXRbWJzR
    ...
```

I want to count the daily frequency of one specific word, say `iphone`, and get the result of its daily frequency like,

```
      date    frequency
2011-01-01    530
2011-01-02    550
...
```

How can I design a program to implement this?

Comment: Take a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017948/word-counts-in-python-using-regular-expression. You need to maybe work row by row. Use `df[column].apply()`, and store counts in another column in DataFrame.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I create a dataframe based on random data, but it should give you an idea on how to go from here. I have the count set to `D` for calendar day, you can change the [offset](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/timeseries.html#offset-aliases) as you need

```
import pandas as pd
import io # only needed to import sample data

data = """
    date          tweet_id    tweet
    2015-10-31    50230       tweet_1
    2015-10-31    48646       tweet_2
    2015-10-31    48748       tweet_3
    2015-10-31    46992       tweet_4
    2015-11-01    46491       tweet_5
    2015-11-01    45347       tweet_6
    2015-11-01    45681       tweet_7
    2015-11-01    46430       tweet_8
    """

df = pd.read_csv(io.StringIO(data), delimiter='\s+', \
                 index_col=False, parse_dates = ['date'])

# Tweet count starts here
df_count = df.set_index('date').resample('D', how='count') # 'D' for offset calendar day
df_count = df_count.drop(df_count.columns[1:], axis=1)
df_count.columns = ['count']

print(df)
```

Just to check what your original `df` looks like

```
        date  tweet_id    tweet
0 2015-10-31     50230  tweet_1
1 2015-10-31     48646  tweet_2
2 2015-10-31     48748  tweet_3
3 2015-10-31     46992  tweet_4
4 2015-11-01     46491  tweet_5
5 2015-11-01     45347  tweet_6
6 2015-11-01     45681  tweet_7
7 2015-11-01     46430  tweet_8
```

After we used [`resample`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.resample.html)

```
print(df_count)

                count
date                 
2015-10-31          4
2015-11-01          4
```

Comment: This only counts how many tweets every day, but I want to count how many times a specific word appear every day. I can count it simply by tweetdata[tweetdata.t_date==u'2012-10-03'].shape[0]

Comment: But this just lets one count the number of tweets per day. The asker wants counts for a particular word by day.

Comment: IMO that's a two part question. But to get you started, you can create a dataframe based on your `tweets` column that has the word `iphone` in it then use what I provided to count the occurences. To get the new dataframe for the specific keyword you can use `nltk`. This is too broad and without any attempt from OP the question becomes a code request which is not what SO is about.

Comment: @PythonNewHand the `resample` lets you do much more than that. You can do every day, every 2 days, every month...

Answer (score -1):

I have solved this problem by myself, here is my solution.

```
import operator
result = tweetdata.groupby('t_date').first();
    allFreq={}
    for date in range(0,result.shape(0)):
        df=tweetdata[tweetdata.t_date==result.index[date]].ix[:,['t_date','tweets']]
        #type(tweetdata.loc[1,'t_date'])
    A=''
    for i in df.index:
        A=A+' '+df.ix[i,1]
    text_file = open("A.txt", "w+")
    text_file.write("%s" % A)
    text_file.close()
    with open('A.txt') as f:
        words = f.read()
        wordfreq = {}
        for word in words.replace(',', ' ').split():
            wordfreq[word] = wordfreq.setdefault(word, 0) + 1

    x = wordfreq
    sorted_x = sorted(x.items(), key=operator.itemgetter(1),reverse=True)
    sorted_x
    allFreq[result.index[date]]=sorted_x
>>>allFreq['2012-06-01']
>>>     [('the', 248),
         ('to', 201),
         ('of', 143),
         ('a', 137),
         ('in', 127),
         ('and', 107),
         ('for', 100),
         ('you', 95),
         ('is', 93),
         ('I', 81),
...]
```