# Display word count in status bar while typing in tkinter text widget

Tags: python, tkinter, tkinter-text

I want to make a simple text editor that displays number of unique words plus total word count as I type. I have tried using `t.get("1.0","end-1c")` but I can't figure out how to make that interactive (live). Toy code from a related answer, where 'keypress' function attempts to print the contents of the text widget to the terminal, is:

```
import tkinter as tk

class textEditor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textFrm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.textFrm.pack(fill = "x")
        self.text = tk.Text(self.textFrm, relief = "flat", font = ("Arial","11"))
        self.text.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
        self.text.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.keyPress())
        self.text.focus()
    def keyPress(self):
        words = self.text.get("1.0","end-1c")
        print(words)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Text editor test")
t = textEditor(root)
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 1):

Don't call`()` the function you're binding.  It's being passed as an arguement to be used as a [callback](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Callback_(computer_programming)).

[Word counts in Python using regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6017948/word-counts-in-python-using-regular-expression)

```
#! /usr/bin/env python3
import tkinter as tk
import re

class textEditor( tk .Frame ):
    def __init__( self, *args, **kwargs ):
        tk .Frame .__init__( self, *args, **kwargs )
        self .textFrm = tk .Frame( self )
        self .textFrm .pack( fill = 'x' )

        self .label = tk .Label( self )
        self .label .pack()

        self .text = tk .Text( self .textFrm,  relief = 'flat',  font = ('Arial','11') )
        self .text .pack( fill = 'both',  expand = True )

        self .text .bind( '<KeyRelease>',  self .keyPress )
        self .text .focus()

    def keyPress( self, event ):
        words = self .text .get( '1.0', 'end-1c' )
        wordcount = len( re .findall( '\w+', words ) )
        self .label .config( text = f'Words: {wordcount}' )

root = tk .Tk()
root .title( 'Text editor test' )
te = textEditor( root )
te .pack()
root .mainloop()
```

Comment: That fixed it, thanks and the regex wordcount functionality was a bonus - although I have used nltk PorterStemmer so I don't double count word tenses and plurals etc.

Comment: Yeah, that was more out'ah my own curiosity while I was trying to figure out why that function wasn't being called.  Didn't spot the `()` right away, put wordcount in while pondering.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, when you `bind` a function, don't call it - don't use `()`

Here is a working solution. It will update the status bar with each keypress

```
import tkinter as tk

class textEditor(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        tk.Frame.__init__(self, *args, **kwargs)
        self.textFrm = tk.Frame(self)
        self.textFrm.pack(fill = "x")
        self.text = tk.Text(self.textFrm, relief = "flat", font = ("Arial","11"))
        self.text.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
        self.text.bind('<KeyRelease>', self.keyPress)
        self.text.focus()
        self.status_bar=tk.Entry(self)
        self.status_bar.pack(fill = "x",side="top")
        
    def keyPress(self,event):
        words = self.text.get("1.0","end-1c")
        self.status_bar.delete(0,"end")
        self.status_bar.insert('end',words)

root = tk.Tk()
root.title("Text editor test")
t = textEditor(root)
t.pack()
root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 0):

Bindings send an event to the function, so you need to change keypress to.

```py
def keypress( self, ev ):
    if len( ev.keysym ) == 1:
        print( ev.keysym, end='' )
```